# Force computed.filter() to update?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I've got a filter that works *once*, with whatever values are pre-initialized in, just at initial initiazation, but never updates.  editstate is a service; in this case it just provides those exposed variables.  So the idea is that when editstate.filterValue and editstate.filterField are changed, the filter should update.

But it doesn't.

I've tried having them be local computed values also, but no dice.  The only programmatic thing that works so far is to unrender and rerender the entire component using a handlebars {{#if toggle.

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
    store: Ember.inject.service(),
    editstate: Ember.inject.service('edit-state'),
    filteredList: Ember.computed.filter('model', function(current, index, all) {
            return current.get(Ember.get(this.get('editstate'), 'filterField')) == Ember.get(this.get('editstate'), 'filterValue');
    }),
```

What am I missing?  I don't see any API for forcing a filter to re-compute, nor to tell it more explicitly to watch these values.

**Update**: I found a *terrible hacky way* to accomplish my goal: In my service, I create *but don't save* a record in the model that I'm filtering, just to force updates.  Whenever the filter parameters change, I update that record with the current time (millis).  And of course it's always filtered out by the filter.

It's ugly, it's probably evil... is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

Define every variable (that you use in computed function) at computed definition:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service(),
  editstate: Ember.inject.service('edit-state'),
  filteredList: Ember.computed('model', 'editstate.filterField', 'editstate.filterValue', function() {
    return this.get('model').filter((current) => {
      return current.get(Ember.get(this.get('editstate'), 'filterField')) === Ember.get(this.get('editstate'), 'filterValue');
    }
  }),
  ...
```

or even more readable:

```
export default Ember.Component.extend({
  store: Ember.inject.service(),
  editstate: Ember.inject.service('edit-state'),
  filteredList: Ember.computed('model', 'editstate.filterField', 'editstate.filterValue', function() {
    let filterField = Ember.get(this, 'editstate.filterField');
    let filterValue = Ember.get(this, 'editstate.filterValue');
    return this.get('model').filterBy(filterField, filterValue);
  }),
  ...
```

Comment: I'm getting that the "callback call is not a function"; it looks from the [Ember source for filter](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.15.3/packages/ember-runtime/lib/computed/reduce_computed_macros.js#L309), filter only accepts one key (array_macro), which only handles [one dependentKey value](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/v2.15.3/packages/ember-runtime/lib/computed/reduce_computed_macros.js#L34).  
Should I be using a different function?  Some other way to add those variables?

Comment: Also, to handle the updates to the `model`, consider using `model.[]` instead of `model` in computed definition. See [computed-properties-and-aggregate-data](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.16.0/object-model/computed-properties-and-aggregate-data/#toc_code-code-vs-code-each-code)

Comment: The inner-most function (the filter) doesn't seem to have access to "this" or anything else local.  Any Ember.get(this, ...) and any this.get(...) fails because  *this* is apparently undefined.  It is defined at the first level (the computed(args, function(){...}) level, just not at the computed(args, function(){filter(function(){-here-...})...})) level.